# 301 Редирект в .htaccess

Tags: redirect, редирект, .htaccess

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста, через `htaccess` сделать редирект со страниц типа

```
http://site.ru/?p=6427&post=167150701_823
http://site.ru/?p=3802?iframe=true&width=900&..
http://site.ru/?p=2487?em_x=22
```

на соответственно
http://site.ru/?p=6427,
http://site.ru/?p=3802,
http://site.ru/?p=2487
Т.е. по сути обрезать все, что идет после ?p=[любое_число].
Пробовал написать

```
RedirectMatch 301 /\?p=([0-9]+).+ /?p=$1
```

Но не срабатывает.

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой .htaccess нужно использовать для удаления лишних параметров из запроса:

```
RewriteEngine On
# проверяем, что запрос идет на /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
# проверяем, что кроме параметра p есть другие параметры (защита от зацикливания)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=\d+$
# получаем значение параметра p из запроса
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bp=(\d+)
# делаем редирект на ссылку только с параметром p
RewriteRule .* /?p=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect 301 /site1/page1.html http://www.site2.com/page2.html
Это пример простого редиректа
http://tods-blog.com.ua/seo-smo/seo/301redirekt/

Comment: тут так просто не получится, регулярка нужна однозначно.